# Return Multiple Sums By Moth For Date Range

Tags: sql, date, sum, range, monthcalendar

I've seen several versions of this problem out there but no solution to my specific one. I have two tables. One of which has 2 numbers to sum up. The tables have no restraints between them. I want a result set that returns the sums for each table by month for a given date range. For instance:

Month   Total_Collections    Total_Expenses

I've attached the schema for the tables:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand Your Problem this solution should do what You expect , 
My Solution was tested at `Oracle` :

It returns counts for given YEAR-MONTH key :

```
SELECT exp.Month , exp.ExpenseCount , coll.CollectionCount 
FROM 
(SELECT  
    TO_CHAR(ExpenseDate, 'YYYY-MM') as Month,
    COUNT(1) as ExpenseCount 
    FROM Expenses 
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ExpenseDate, 'YYYY-MM')
) exp ,
(SELECT  
    TO_CHAR(CollectionDate, 'YYYY-MM') as Month,
    COUNT(1) as  CollectionCount
    FROM Collection  
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CollectionDate, 'YYYY-MM')
) coll 
WHERE exp.Month = coll.Month ;
```

Example output :

```
MONTH     | EXPENSECOUNT | COLLECTIONCOUNT 
2017-11           1              1 
2017-12           2              3
```

Comment: You can also use `EXTRACT` with `YEAR_MONTH` all depends on what kind of Time range You need.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using "Extract"? I'm running into issues with the "To_Char" function because because I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Hey guys. I'm marking the code above as correct because is was very helpful in coming up with the solution that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT exp.Month , exp.ExpenseCount , coll.CollectionCount 
FROM 
(SELECT  
    Convert(VARCHAR(6), Expenses.ExpenseDate, 112) as Month,
    SUM(Expenses.ExpenseAmount) as ExpenseCount 
    FROM Expenses 
    GROUP BY Convert(VARCHAR(6),Expenses.ExpenseDate, 112)
) exp ,
(SELECT  
    Convert(VARCHAR(6),Collection.CollectionDate, 112) as Month,
    SUM(Collection.CashAmount) as  CollectionCount
    FROM Collection  
    GROUP BY Convert(VARCHAR(6),Collection.CollectionDate, 112)
) coll 
WHERE exp.Month = coll.Month
```